# Module missing error

Tags: python-3.x, pyside, py2exe

I have created the exe by using py2exe and this works fine in windows 8 , Application window runs without python installing. But same distribution or exe gives an error in windows 7 and windows XP. Below is the traceback for the same.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 93, in get_pyside_dir
      File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
      File "<loader>", line 8, in __load
    ImportError: (DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.) 'C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\123\\dist\\PySide.QtCore.pyd'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TopicMapParser.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PySide\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PySide\__init__.py", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 95, in get_pyside_dir
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 88, in _get_win32_case_sensitive_name
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 63, in _get_win32_short_name
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Please help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We are shooting into the dark when you don't post your code. So please, next time, please post your code.

Look at the errors. Python has excellent error handling and naming conventions to make it really clear on whats going wrong. It can't find the module that you are requesting. Have you attempted to update your python? To attempt to find the module that you are attempting to import? Have you double checked to make sure you did not misspell the module name? Have you searched around on stackoverflow for existing similar questions?

You are getting an *ImportError* and *FileNotFoundError* meaning it is not installed, file path is broken or you misspelled the module name.

It seems like you are trying to install QtCore, which is a package that you need to manually install using ***sudo apt-get install python-qt4***. For windows, you have to install something that allows you to do *apt-get* since it is a Unix/Linux command. Try using [wuinstall](https://www.wuinstall.com).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to generate the exe by using Py2exe in Python 3.4. It creates the exe and it works fine in the same machine. But it was giving an error in other machine. I have also tried with cx-freeze , still I was not able to resolve the issue. But I installed the Pyside in Python 2.7 and used py2exe for the same version and it worked nicely.

Below is the code that I have used in setup.py.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
data = [('', [r'hpXMLTools.ico']), ('imageformats',[r'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PySide\plugins\imageformats\qico4.dll'])]
setup(windows=[{'script': 'TopicMapParser.py',
                'icon_resources': [(1, 'hpXMLTools.ico')]
               }],
      data_files=data,
      options={
          'py2exe':
              {
              'optimize': 2
              }
      }, requires=['PySide', 'xlsxwriter'])
```